# TMUX issue on Ubuntu: always have a line of text at the top of new session

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gradle, tmux

I have installed the TMUX(2.7) on my ubuntu 16.04, there is a line of text always  be at the top of the new session:
 -bash: export: `GRADLE-OPTS=-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true': not a valid identifier

[image]

Comment: Is it only at the top of the window, or does it repeat if you type <return>? Could it be a side effect of something in your prompt (`$PS1`)? You've got *something* trying to set `GRADLE-OPTS` (with a hyphen); it should be `$GRADLE_OPTS` (with an underscore).

Comment: Yeah this doesn't sound like a tmux issue; it's bash complaining. iirc tmux spawns a login shell by default so its likely code in a file that is only sourced by bash when launched as a login shell. Check files like `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.proflie`, and `/etc/profile` for the buggy code.